# NSFileHandleReadCompletionNotification not posting

Tags: objective-c

I'm having an issue with NSFileHandleReadCompletionNotification not posting. I'm piping the results of one NSTask into another one. For whatever reason my getData method just will not be called. Any ideas? Both tasks are working properly because I'm getting the expected files written to my hard drive. Just no notification.

```
- (void) encodeVideo:(NSString*)path
{
    NSString* ffmpegPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ffmpeg" ofType:@""];
    NSString* presetFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"128" ofType:@"ffpreset"];

    NSTask* encodeTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray* arguments = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arguments addObject:@"-y"];
    [arguments addObject:@"-i"];
    [arguments addObject:path];
    [arguments addObject:@"-f"];
    [arguments addObject:@"mpegts"];
    [arguments addObject:@"-ac"];
    [arguments addObject:@"2"];
    [arguments addObject:@"-fpre"];
    [arguments addObject:presetFile];
    [arguments addObject:@"-s"];
    [arguments addObject:@"320x240"];
    [arguments addObject:@"-aspect"];
    [arguments addObject:@"320:240"];
    [arguments addObject:@"-async"];
    [arguments addObject:@"2"];
    [arguments addObject:@"-"];

    [encodeTask setLaunchPath: ffmpegPath];
    [encodeTask setArguments: arguments];
    [encodeTask setStandardOutput:[NSPipe pipe]];

    NSMutableArray* segmentArguments = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [segmentArguments addObject:@"-t"];
    [segmentArguments addObject:@"10"];
    [segmentArguments addObject:@"-f"];
    [segmentArguments addObject:@"/Users/Morgan/Desktop/LiveStreamServer/video"];
    [segmentArguments addObject:@"-S"];
    [segmentArguments addObject:@"1"];

    NSString* segmenterPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mediastreamsegmenter" ofType:@""];
    NSLog(@"%@", segmenterPath);
    NSTask* segmentTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];

    [segmentTask setLaunchPath: segmenterPath];
    [segmentTask setArguments: segmentArguments];

    [segmentTask setStandardInput:[encodeTask standardOutput]];
    [segmentTask setStandardOutput:[NSPipe pipe]];
    [segmentTask setStandardError:[NSPipe pipe]];

    NSFileHandle *file = [[segmentTask standardOutput] fileHandleForReading];
    [file readInBackgroundAndNotify];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(getData:) name:NSFileHandleReadCompletionNotification object:file];

    [segmentTask launch];
    [encodeTask launch];

    [arguments release];
    [segmentArguments release];
}

- (void) getData: (NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSData *data = [[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:@"NSFileHandleNotificationDataItem"];
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@", string);
    [[aNotification object] readInBackgroundAndNotify];
}
```

Comment: I know you've resolved the problem already. I'd jut like to add a comment, because this is a common mistake that many people make. You should always use the definitions provided by the system, so it' a good idea to use NSFileHandleNotificationDataItem instead of @"NSFileHandleNotificationDataItem" because if you misspell a string, you'll get problems that are difficult to find. If you misspell a definition provided in the header-files, you'll just get a compile-error and can spot it immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to read the stdError in the background as well. Had it outputting into a pipe, but wasn't reading it so the buffer got filled up.

Comment: Can you please explain your answer.  Perhaps you can share your fixed code.  I am having the same problem and am pulling my hair out trying to solve it!